# problems installing Pango-1.30.1

Tags: cairo, pango

I have encountered a problem installing Pango-1.30 on a Ubuntu 12.04 platform. During ./configure step I receive a message saying "Could not enable any of Freetype, X11, Cairo, or Win32 backends.  Must have at least one backend to build Pango".  However, I have build and installed Freetype and X11 and they are located in /usr/bin.  How do I inform ./configure where to get them?

Thanks,
Mark Allyn

Answer (score 5):

Ensure you have all the dependencies installed, you can find them in the README file.

They are:

- fontconfig
- FreeType
- HarfBuzz